# Using a complex sql query to check availability of date/room using JCalendar

Tags: java, mysql

I have to check the rooms available during a particular period ie from a starting date to an ending one for a hotel reservation system. To choose a starting and ending date, I used a JCalendar. The problem is that I am getting an error when I am creating the SQL string query and also I don't know how to retrieve the date from the JCalendar to be used in the query.

Below are code snippets of what I have done and where I am stucked.

JCalendar instantiation:

```
JDateChooser arrival = new JDateChooser();
JDateChooser departure = new JDateChooser();
```

Query to check for rooms available:

```
       ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String connectionUser = "root";
        String connectionPassword = "admin";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser,
                connectionPassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from testing.room as ro
            where ro.room_id not in 
        (
          select re.room_no
          from testing.booking as re 
          where (arrival_date >= "2016-05-24" and departure_date < "2016-05-29")
            or (departure_date >= "2016-05-24" and arrival_date < "2016-05-29")
         )";

        rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2)
                    + " " + rs.getString(3)+ " " + rs.getString(4)+ " "+ rs.getString(5));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have hardcoded the dates here :

```
          where (arrival_date >= "2016-05-24" and departure_date < "2016-05-29")
            or (departure_date >= "2016-05-24" and arrival_date < "2016-05-29")
```

That's because I don't know how to take the values from the JCalendar to write it there ie should I use PreparedStatements and get the text or something?

And also, I am getting an error with the query ie where I wrote String query= "query" as it says "Insert missing quotes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes here:

- Get the dates from `JDateChooser` fields (by calling `getDate()` method on `JDateChooser` objects).
- Use `PreparedStatement` and set the dates dynamically. Below is an exmple:

  ```
  JDateChooser arrival = new JDateChooser();
  JDateChooser departure = new JDateChooser();

  PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from testing.room where arrival_date >= ? and departure_date < ?");
  pStmt.setDate(1, arrival.getDate());
  pStmt.setDate(2, departure.getDate());
  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I had to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date. The thing is, I can't do that `select` because my Room table in the database doesn't have the fields `arrival_date` and `departure_date` that's why I had to use a complex query(where I used the Booking table which has room_no as foreign key) where I am getting an error of "missing quotes". Tried breaking the complex query string but still getting an error.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me immensely! I just have to escape the quotes or parentheses in the query now